# QCameraViewFinder weird layout on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, qt

I want to show a simple viewfinder for the camera on an iPhone 6 with Qt for iOS. Everything is working but the viewfinder's position is wrong as shown in the image (i am simply adding the viewfinder to the central widget which occupies the whole Main Window). I also tried viewfinder->setFixedHeight (and width); this changes the viewfinder's size but the position is still offset... Anybody know how to fix this?

Here's my code (copied from the docs):

```
    ui->setupUi(this);

    camera = new QCamera;
    viewfinder = new QCameraViewfinder(ui->centralWidget);
    viewfinder->show();
    camera->setViewfinder(viewfinder);
    imageCapture = new QCameraImageCapture(camera);
    camera->setCaptureMode(QCamera::CaptureStillImage);

    camera->start();

    //on half pressed shutter button
    camera->searchAndLock();

    //on shutter button pressed
    imageCapture->capture();

    //on shutter button released
    camera->unlock();
```

[image: iPhone 6 screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

A temporary solution might be to set fixed height and width.
See https://forum.qt.io/topic/64971/qcameraviewfinder-weird-layout-on-ios/5